# How do I combine multiple executables? (Windows)

Tags: python, subprocess, pyinstaller, executable

I have a python script that calls up to 4 executables in the same folder using the subprocess() function.  I converted the python script to .exe using pyinstaller but want to combine all 5 executables into one .exe for the sake of (others) convenience.  How do I do this?  I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: This is not so much a python question, as it is a something-else-question, excuse me for not being able to come up with a proper term.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge two exe files into one programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268515/merge-two-exe-files-into-one-programmatically)

Comment: do you need one exe for installer or for executing the python program?